# CSS :active not working on <a> tags

Tags: html, css, button

i'm working on a set of buttons for people to use in their pages but the css :active attribute is not working on the `<a>` tag.

I have it on [CSSDeck](http://cssdeck.com/labs/pyj0s8p7) and [JSfIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thediex09/gkc2c/) if you want to have a play with it. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Write your code here, explain what you wanted it to be like and what the problem is

Comment: You don't have an :active setting for your <a> tag?

Comment: AFAIK you can't apply `:active` to a button. Its only for anchor tag. Have a look at this: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp

Comment: @AnkitPopli thats not true. You can apply `:active` to many or any elements.

Comment: You can apply :active to a button. I just did it. @datPYBER - in the future, trimming down your code into something smaller is helpful - like this - http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/L3h58/

Comment: @sheriffderek. your snippet made it clear. thanks a lot

Comment: Sure thing. I always strip my code to the bare necessities and I get to my problem a lot faster. @Prakash had the correct answer though for sure. Just not an A+ explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**CODE**:

`<a class="button" href="#">KABLAM</a>`

Your css port `button:active` just works for the `active` state of `button` tag. There is no `active` property defined for your `a` tag or `button` class. You should make the definition as `a:active` or `.button:active`.

```
button:active, a:active{
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left top,
        left bottom,
        color-stop(0, #2E9185),
        color-stop(1, #00FFE6)
    );
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #2E9185 0%, #00FFE6 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #2E9185 0%, #00FFE6 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #2E9185 0%, #00FFE6 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #2E9185 0%, #00FFE6 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #2E9185 0%, #00FFE6 100%);
}
```

Now this looks to be working properly